# How to replace attribute and keep it after callback executed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback, attributes, aspxgridview

I'm newbie in javascript. So, I need some help.
I have ASPxGridView on WebForm and I want to run my code when "Clear" button clicked. I mean embeded button in ASPxGridView, which placed in SearchPanel. So, I placed this code in javascript:

```
window.onload = function (s, e){
document.getElementById("gridFileList_DXCBtn1").removeAttribute("data-args");
document.getElementById("gridFileList_DXCBtn1").setAttribute("onclick", "gridFileList.PerformCallback();");
}
```

It works perfect, but after callback, when I click again on this button my code doesn't run again, I see, that this button has again its attribute "data-args" and has no my attribute "onclick".

Window.onload does not fired after callback, so can you explain me what event I need to use for decribed behavior on that button?

Comment: Check the console, do you get any errors?

Comment: Pls post a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found that the button looks like recreated each time, when it is pressed. So I made a trick. I wrote in body section

```
<body onclick="OnClick(event);">
```

and in script section:

```
function OnClick(e) {
    if (e != undefined && e.target.className == "dx-vam" && e.target.localName == "span" && e.target.textContent == "Очистить") {
        var btn = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        if (btn.attributes[btn.attributes.length - 1].name == "data-args") {
            btn.removeAttribute("data-args");
        }
        gridFileList.PerformCallback();
    }
}
```